# Review snippets  Invalid object type for field ‘author’

Tags: wordpress, google-rich-snippets

I got the following warning under Google Search Console.

Review snippets  Invalid object type for field ‘author’

I have setup Knowledge Graph & Schema.org
organizaton
uploaded a logo as well

The page I need help with: https://instituteofsport.co.nz/free-consultation

How can i solve this warning please help me on this can’t find any solution yet

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the `Review` markup, it doesn't have a required value, it has `Text` as a value, while the docs require this:

> author     Person or Organization
>
> https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/review-snippet#review-properties

you need to replace this:

```
"author": "Author name",
```

with this:

```
"author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Author name"
},
```